# Is this problem on unambiguous DNFs hard?

Tags: np-hardness

Call a [DNF formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) $\varphi = \bigvee_{i=1}^n C_i$ *unambiguous* if for every $i\neq j$,
$C_i \land C_j$ is unsatisfiable. In other words, the disjunct $C_i$ contains some literal $l$ and $C_j$ contains the negation of $l$.

Consider the following problem.

**INPUT:** An unambiguous DNF formula over variables $\overline{X} = X_1,\ldots,X_n$, and natural numbers $\overline{w} = w_1,\ldots,w_n$ given in binary.

**OUTPUT:** The maximum weight of an assignment $\tau: \overline{X} \to \{0,1\}$ that does *not* satisfy $\varphi$, where the weight of $\tau$ is defined by $\mathrm{weight}_{\overline{w}}(\tau) = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \tau(x_i)$. Let us write this quantity $\max_{\tau \not\models \varphi} \mathrm{weight}_{\overline{w}}(\tau)$. (With the convention that the max over an empty set is $-\infty$, in case $\varphi$ is a tautology.)

If you prefer, you can make this a decision problem by adding an integer $t$ as part of the input and asking whether $\max_{\tau \not\models \varphi} \mathrm{weight}_{\overline{w}}(\tau)$ is bigger than $t$.

**Question:** What is the complexity of this problem? I am hoping that it is hard; ideally I would like a proof of NP-hardness, but at this point I would also be happy with weaker evidence such as assuming SETH, or even NSETH [a].

**Some observations:**

- The (decision version) is in NP: simply guess a valuation $\tau$ and check that it is not satisfying and that its weight is bigger than $t$.
- The problem is NP-complete if you remove the restriction that DNF formulas be unambiguous (trivial reduction from DNF falsifiability).
- If instead of $\max_{\tau \not\models \varphi} \mathrm{weight}_{\overline{w}}(\tau)$ you want to compute $\max_{\tau \models \varphi} \mathrm{weight}_{\overline{w}}(\tau)$ (i.e., the max is over the *satisfying* assignments), then the problem is PTIME, even over arbitrary DNFs. Indeed you can simply compute the max for each disjunct, and then take the max of these.
- If the weights in $\overline{w}$ are given in unary then the problem is PTIME, i.e., the problem is in [pseudo polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time). Indeed, for every value $A$ between $0$ and $\sum_i w_i$, we can compute in PTIME by dynamic programming the number of *satisfying* assignments of weight $A$, hence deduce if there is a non-satisfying assignment having weight $A$.

Note that this is a simpler version of [this previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/48815/38111) about the same problem but for unambiguous finite automata instead of DNF formulas, in the sense that there is a PTIME reduction from the problem of the current post to the one about automata.

[a] *Carmosino, Marco L.; Gao, Jiawei; Impagliazzo, Russell; Mihajlin, Ivan; Paturi, Ramamohan; Schneider, Stefan*, [**Nondeterministic extensions of the strong exponential time hypothesis and consequences for non-reducibility**](https://doi.org/10.1145/2840728.2840746), Proceedings of the 7th ACM conference on innovations in theoretical computer science, ITCS’16, Cambridge, MA, USA, January 14–16, 2016. New York, NY: Association for Computing Machinery (ACM) (ISBN 978-1-4503-4057-1). 261-270 (2016). [ZBL1334.68079](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1334.68079).